# Python Thread with Queue

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

i try to get working python thread with queue. But when i put any value to queue i cannt find this value in other thread.

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import time
class ThreadWorker(object):
    verbose = True
    thread = None
    queue = Queue()

    def __init__(self, workerId, queueMaxSize = 50, emptyQueuewaitTime = 1):
        self.queue.maxsize = queueMaxSize
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.__work, args=(workerId, emptyQueuewaitTime))
        self.thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.thread.start()

    def __work(self, workerId, sl):
        while(True):
            if self.queue.empty:
                print '[THREAD_WORKER] id: {}, EMPTY QUEUE sleeping: {}'.format(workerId, sl)
                time.sleep(sl) 
                continue
            if self.verbose:
                print '[THREAD_WORKER] id: {}, queueSize: {}'.format(workerId, self.queue.qsize())
            d = self.queue.get()
            self.queue.task_done()

    def put(self, item, waitIfFull = True):
        self.queue.put(item, waitIfFull)
        if self.verbose:
            print "Add to queue, current queue size: {}".format(self.queue.qsize())
```

Create instance and fill the queue ...

```
t = ThreadWorker("t1")
t.put("item1")
t.put("item2")
t.put("item3")
```

Output from thread with name t1 is: [THREAD_WORKER] id: t1, EMPTY QUEUE sleeping: 1

But in queue are three items ....

Comment: `queue.empty` is a method; you need to call it. Also, checking whether a queue is empty is generally a very bug-prone way to interact with it; just calling `get` is less prone to race conditions.

Comment: @user2357112 Please post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Also you probably don't want to make queue and thread class attributes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`queue.empty` is a method; you need to call it. That's the immediate issue.

If you create two ThreadWorkers, you're going to find that they're sharing their `queue`s. Unlike other languages, an assignment like `queue = Queue()` at class level doesn't declare an instance variable; it declares a class attribute. To create an instance attribute, you would instead assign `self.queue = Queue()` in the `__init__` method. There is no need for any sort of declaration of this attribute's existence at class level.

Finally, checking whether a `Queue` is empty is very prone to race conditions, since whether or not it's empty might change between `empty()` and `get()`. It's generally better to just call `get`, and let `get` wait for a `put` if the queue is empty.